# Pandas: how do I select(filter) a subgroup within a subgroup?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to filter a dataset for a subgroup, then filter within EACH subgroup.

In the example I'm looking to select the artists that can sing both 'Do' and 'Re' and can sing EACH of those in both 'Major' and 'minor'. In this case, only 'Alice' would satisfy that condition.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'artist': 'Alice Alice Alice Alice Alice Bob Bob Bob Claire Claire'.split(),
                   'note': 'Do Do Re Re Mi Do Do Re Do Do'.split(),
                   'key': 'Major minor Major minor Major minor Major minor Major \
     minor'.split(),})
df

    artist  note  key
0   Alice   Do    Major
1   Alice   Do    minor
2   Alice   Re    Major
3   Alice   Re    minor
4   Alice   Mi    Major
5   Bob     Do    minor
6   Bob     Do    Major
7   Bob     Re    minor
8   Claire  Do    Major
9   Claire  Do    minor
```

desired output:

```
    artist  note  key
0   Alice   Do    Major
1   Alice   Do    minor
2   Alice   Re    Major
3   Alice   Re    minor
4   Alice   Mi    Major
```

This is what I initially tried:

```
df=df.groupby('artist').filter(lambda x: (set(x['note'])>=set(['Do','Re'])) & (set (x['scale']) >= 
set(['Major','minor']) )   )
df
    artist  note  key
0   Alice   Do    Major
1   Alice   Do    minor
2   Alice   Re    Major
3   Alice   Re    minor
4   Alice   Mi    Major
5   Bob     Do    minor
6   Bob     Do    Major
7   Bob     Re    minor
```

the problem of course is that Bob can sing both 'Do' and 'Re' and can sing in both 'Major' and 'minor', so both conditions in the filter are satisfied. But he can't sing each of the notes in all the required keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `groupby` + `filter`  with custom `filter` function which returns a boolean value per group representing the condition where the *artists that can sing both 'Do' and 'Re' and can sing EACH of those in both 'Major' and 'minor'*:

```
def f(g):
    s = g['note'] + '-' + g['key']
    return np.all([s.eq(x).any()
                   for x in ('Do-Major', 'Do-minor', 'Re-Major', 'Re-minor')])

df.groupby('artist').filter(f)
```

Alternative approach with `groupby` + `nunique` along with `boolean indexing` to filter groups:

```
m = df['note'].isin(['Do', 'Re']) & df['key'].isin(['Major', 'minor'])
s = (df['note'] + '-' + df['key'])[m].groupby(df['artist']).nunique().eq(4)
df.loc[df['artist'].isin(s[s].index)]
```

Result:

```
  artist note    key
0  Alice   Do  Major
1  Alice   Do  minor
2  Alice   Re  Major
3  Alice   Re  minor
4  Alice   Mi  Major
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a new column that combines the two search columns. From there, you can `groupby` the `artist` return a list of unique values that is then joined into a string. From there, you can use some `regex` which functions as `AND` within `str.contains` to see which artist contain all of the keywords in the joined string:

```
s = (df[['artist']].assign(notekey=df['note'] + df['key'])
     .groupby('artist')['notekey'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique()))
     .str.contains(r'(?=.*DoMajor)(?=.*ReMajor)(?=.*Dominor)(?=.*Reminor)',regex=True))
df[df['artist'].isin([*s[s].index])]

Out[1]: 
  artist note    key
0  Alice   Do  Major
1  Alice   Do  minor
2  Alice   Re  Major
3  Alice   Re  minor
4  Alice   Mi  Major
```

Answer (score 1):

Groupby with set intersection is one possible way to achieve your result:

```
result = (
    df.groupby(["key", "note"])
    .agg(set)
    .loc[[("Major", "Do"), ("Major", "Re"), 
          ("minor", "Do"), ("minor", "Re")], "artist"]
    .tolist()
)

unique_artists = set.intersection(*result)

df.loc[df.artist.isin(unique_artists)]

    artist  note    key
0   Alice   Do  Major
1   Alice   Do  minor
2   Alice   Re  Major
3   Alice   Re  minor
4   Alice   Mi  Major
```